# I can't see myself chat in Team Fortress 2

Tags: team-fortress-2

I was playing on a server the other day, and I could see myself speak. The next day, I went back on, and I could not. I can see everybody else talk, and they can still see me talk. I am running Team Fortress 2 on a Windows 7 PC.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: text chat or voice chat?

Comment: You can't see your messages in the text chat box? Or you can't see the little popup on the HUD when you're using the microphone? You'll need to clarify this for us

Comment: It might be a server plugin, I've noticed that I can't see my own voice commands on some servers

Comment: In the chat box there should be a "filters" button, double-check that it's set correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If others can see what you are typing but you cannot, open the console using the tilde (~) key and type: **cl_mute_all_commands 0**

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally muted yourself in the mute menu

Comment: It would be good if you gave steps on how to unmute himself if this is the case :)